# Excel VBA Userform - How to increase/decrease date by one month

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Using the following code, I increase the value of the date displayed in TextBox with SpinButtons.

```
MainUserForm_Initialize()
DateTextBox.Value = Format(Date, "dd-mm-YYYY")
...
End Sub

'Add one day when spinning up.
Private Sub SpinButtonDate1_SpinUp()
    With DateTextBox
        .Value = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, .Value), "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End With
End Sub

'Remove one day when spinning down.
Private Sub SpinButtonDate1_SpinDown()
    With DateTextBox
        .Value = Format(DateAdd("d", -1, .Value), "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is, if I would spin down to 11-07-2015, it goes from 12-07-2015 to 06-12-2015 instead of 11-07-2015. Why is that? (I have the same problem when increasing the value. The dates given are just an example.)

Comment: Dates are "Americanized" in VBA and are interpreted as mm/dd/yyyy.  My guess is the .Value is not what you expect it is  (I know you're applying the "Format", but the format just changes how the dates are visualized, not actually interpreted).  Have a look at the DateSerial function (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateserial.php)

Comment: Are your regional settings set to use mm/dd/yyyy date order by any chance? That would cause the problem you describe - and confuse me as to why you want to display the dates in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have the same issue if I set my regional format to US. Try this fix which should work regardless of your regional settings:

```
'Add one day when spinning up.
Private Sub SpinButtonDate1_SpinUp()
    With DateTextBox
        .Value = Format(GetDateFromUK(.Value) + 1, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End With
End Sub

'Remove one day when spinning down.
Private Sub SpinButtonDate1_SpinDown()
    With DateTextBox
        .Value = Format(GetDateFromUK(.Value) - 1, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    End With
End Sub
Function GetDateFromUK(sDate As String, Optional sSeparator As String = "-") As Date
    Dim vParts
    vParts = Split(sDate, sSeparator)
    GetDateFromUK = DateSerial(vParts(2), vParts(1), vParts(0))
End Function
```